# PHP: How to remove all char from a string?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove every non numeric char a string except dots and commas in PHP , how can I do that please. I am using PHP 5.6

I am trying something like `return preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/", "", $string);`

Sample string: @@ @@ -'1234567A' +'12,345.67

Comment: Your regex doesn't work? Can you provide a sample of the string?

Comment: @@ @@
-'1234567A'
+'12,345.67

Comment: @user3433309: You should also provide expected outputs .

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to remove every non numeric char

So you want to remove all that is not a number, which would leave you with only numbers. That could be done with:

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $string)
```

But

> except dots and commas

So we also need to ignore dots and commas:

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9.,]/', '', $string)
```

But the result of this on your sample does not make much sense:
123456712,345.67

Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: This is great, but you should escape ., and also I think the string can be multiline so it should be '/[^0-9\.,]/m' :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data = '{123,.., 456, 231, 478, 123, 673}';
    $data=preg_replace('/[^,.]/', "", $data);
    echo $data;
```

**Output**

```
,..,,,,,
```